# Vagrant up fails with Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, centos7, vagrant-windows

Upgraded to vagrant version 2.1.1 and latest centos/7 (virtualbox, 1803.01) and *$vagrant up* now fails to build just after the new key is loaded.  The Vagrant file being used has run fine on previous versions of vagrant (2.0.3).

Interestingly I am able to connect to the instance manually using vagrant, using the new key both using direct ssh and also with:

> $vagrant ssh nat

**Things already tried:**
Extended timeout within vagrant *config.vm.boot_timeout = 1200*
Uninstalled both vagrant and virtualbox + manually removing plugins and removing both *C:\Users\owner\.vagrand.d* and *C:\Users\owner\.VirtualBox* directories before reinstall
Tried older version of *nat.vm.box_version = "1704.01"* which previous worked.

**Why not roll back?**
Initially I upgraded as I was having another issue which I will raise a separate thread about. Will link here once I have created it.

**Versions**
Host OS: Windows 7 Professional
Guest OS: centos/7 1803.01

Vagrant Version: 2.1.1

Vagrant Plugin list:
vagrant-hostmanager (1.8.8)
vagrant-hosts (2.8.1)
vagrant-proxyconf (1.5.2)
vagrant-reload (0.0.1)
vagrant-share (1.1.9)
vagrant-vbguest (0.15.1)

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'nat' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'fei' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> nat: Importing base box 'centos/7'...
==> nat: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> nat: Checking if box 'centos/7' is up to date...
==> nat: Setting the name of the VM: brand_nat_1526342206425_95671
==> nat: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> nat: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> nat: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    nat: Adapter 1: nat
    nat: Adapter 2: intnet
==> nat: Forwarding ports...
    nat: 22 (guest) => 2200 (host) (adapter 1)
==> nat: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> nat: Booting VM...
==> nat: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    nat: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
    nat: SSH username: vagrant
    nat: SSH auth method: private key
    nat: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    nat: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    nat: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    nat: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    nat:
    nat: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    nat: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    nat:
    nat: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    nat: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    nat: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
    nat: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    nat: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    nat: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    nat: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    nat: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    nat: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    nat: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    nat: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    nat: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

Also showing my slightly sanitized vagrant file.  None of the scripts listed actually get run as the box fails before they are executed.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# abbreviated brand name
BRAND_NAME = "brand"
TOP_LEVEL_DOMAIN = ".some.dev"
BOX_NAME = "centos/7"

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "virtualbox"
  config.vm.boot_timeout = 1200

  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-proxyconf")
    config.proxy.http     = "http://192.168.100.3:3128/"
    config.proxy.https    = "https://192.168.100.3:3128/"
    config.proxy.no_proxy = "localhost,127.0.0.1,.some.lan"
  end

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
    vb.memory = 2048
    vb.cpus = 2
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpuexecutioncap", "50"]
  end

  config.vm.define "nat" do |nat|
    nat.vm.box = BOX_NAME
    nat.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.2", virtualbox__intnet: true
    nat.vm.hostname = "nat.staging." + BRAND_NAME + TOP_LEVEL_DOMAIN
    nat.vm.provision :hosts, :sync_hosts => true
    nat.vm.provision "shell", path: "./scripts/aws_replication.sh"
    nat.vm.provision "shell", path: "./scripts/nat_ssh.sh"
    nat.vm.provision "shell", path: "./scripts/nat_staging.sh"
    nat.vm.provision "shell", path: "./scripts/nat_git_clone.sh"
    nat.vm.provision "shell", path: "./scripts/nat_set_ansible.sh"
  end

  config.vm.define "fei" do |fei|
    fei.vm.box = BOX_NAME
    fei.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.4", virtualbox__intnet: true
    fei.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80, auto_correct: true
    fei.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 443, auto_correct: true
    fei.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9000, host: 9000, auto_correct: true
    fei.vm.provision :hosts, :sync_hosts => true
    fei.vm.hostname = BRAND_NAME + ".staging" + TOP_LEVEL_DOMAIN
    fei.vm.provision "shell", path: "./scripts/aws_replication.sh"
    fei.vm.provision "shell", path: "./scripts/non-nat_key_staging.sh"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

nat: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
 nat: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.

Every time you are running "Vagrant up" command it tries to find insecure key and replace it.To use default key mentioned at path "config.ssh.private_key_path" include below entry in Vagrantfile.

Use **config.ssh.insert_key = false** in your Vagrantfile and then try.

Comment: Can you please tell us where to the Vagrantfile located? Thanks in advance!

Comment: On Windows complete path to Vagrant file is:                                     C:\Users\your username\.vagrant.d\boxes\laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead\9.1.0\virtualbox\Vagrantfile

Answer (score -1):

I use OSX, I resolved this problem by restart my computer.

Comment: this can safely go as a comment